# Which is simpliest way to "threadify" a springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

I start in java / springboot and I want to distribute an export function (initially a single class managed by SpingApplication), in several small classes performing an export chunk executed simultaneously.

```
/* 
Here is my initial application class setted conventionally according to SpringBoot practice ...
Which works but it's too long
*/

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Exporter.class, args);
        Exporter exporter = ctx.getBean(Exporter.class);
        exporter.main(args);
    }
}


/* The runnable classe in Exporter.java*/
package moteur;

import config.ClauseWhereConfig;
import config.FtpConfig;
import config.PigeExportHighcoConfig;
import config.Sql2oConfig;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({ ExportSession.class})
public class Exporter {

    @Autowired
    private ExportSession currentExport;

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Exporter.class);

    public void main(String[] args) {
        run(args);
    }

public void run(String[] args) {
/*do some stuff ... */
}



/* 
Then I tried this :

Each exporter instance is supposed to make a piece of "select from" original (as you know with the keyword limit <from>, <to>
*/

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Exporter.class, args);
        Exporter exporter1 = ctx.getBean(Exporter.class);
        Exporter exporter2 = ctx.getBean(Exporter.class);

        exporter1.setName("exporter1");
        exporter2.setName("exporter2");
        exporter1.start();
        exporter2.start();

    }
}

/* The Exporter class now extends Thread object */

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
@Import({ ExportSession.class, Sql2oConfig.class, ClauseWhereConfig.class, FtpConfig.class, PigeExportHighcoConfig.class})
public class Exporter extends Thread {

    @Autowired
    private ExportSession currentExport;

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Exporter.class);

    public void main(String[] args) {
        run(args);
    }

    public void run(String[] args) {
        logger.info(getName() + "---- >: Is running"  ) ;

}
```

This foolish attempt that of course doesn't work :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at moteur.Application.main(Application.java:27)
```

In fact i'm loking for a solution for a small autonomous batch treatment 
have you got this ?

Comment: "distribute an export function in several small classes performing an export chunk executed simultaneously" - I am not sure this is a correct English phrase. I cannot understand it.

Comment: Surely  My english is not perfect :-)
I try to explain : basicly my original application returns a result of 1000 rows" from a select" on my database. 
That I want for instance is to set 10 threads that each returns a chunk of  100 rows "simultaneously".
I hope it is a little more clear ;-)

Comment: that is not going to be faster. if you wanted to say make several unrelated web calls then you should do the async. or if you want to fetch the list all as 1 then break it into chunks to perform processing on, but hitting a db is expensive best to do it once and let the db optimize.

Comment: Thx. Maybe I should be more specific: First of all, my application is not intended to manage  web services. It rather atcs like a stand-alone batch process. The use of Springboot tools is just a convenience for beans management . Also, the process gets a list of thousands stores to inventory. A  sequentially request for select this thousands entities will necessarily be slower than 100 concurrent requests that gets the same scope. (I've made some tests on cmd line and I gain around 30% ).

Comment: looks like exporter1 and exporter2 are the same instance. So  exporter2.start() tries to start already started thread, hence the error.

Comment: anyway, making a Spring bean of type Thread is a bad idea. Make it of type Runnable, then create a thread with it as a parameter just before you want to start a thread.

Comment: Thanks Alexei i wll try this and inform this thread for the feed back

Comment: Ok the the solution of Alexei suits me well. Thx again.
just, I don't know how to mark my question as solved :-).